# Asymptotics for $|x-y|^{-2}$ for small $|y|$ and large $|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics

Suppose we are in some ball $|y|\le R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, suppose $|x|\ge 2R$. I'd like to show $|x-y|^{-2} = |x|^{-2} + \mathcal{O}(|x|^{-3})$.

There's a hint to write $$|x-y|^{-2} = |x|^{-2}\left ( 1- \frac{2x\cdot y}{|x|^2}+\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}\right )^{-1},$$

which is easy to show. From here, I've tried showing
$$
\left ( 1- \frac{2x\cdot y}{|x|^2}+\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}\right )^{-1} \le 1 +C|x|^{-1}
$$
using the assumptions to find a candidate for $C$, but I can't seem to manipulate it in such a way to get this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\frac{2x\cdot y}{|x|^2}-\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}$. Suppose $m$ is non-negative. Then one can show that $m<1$, so you could write the series expansion

$$|x-y|^{-2} = |x|^{-2}(1+m+m^2+...),$$

from which the estimate follows.

If $m$ is negative, $(1-m)^{-1} < 1$ and there is no need to expand.

Comment: can you explain why is $|m|<1$?

Comment: Thank you!  And @Marios Gretsas, Cauchy-Schwarz on the first term then using the assumptions gives you $m\le 1-|y|^2/|x|^2 \le 1$. One can show $m=1$ holds only if $x=y$, which can't happen in this case. So $m<1$. The fact that ougoah wrote $|m|$ makes me think they did it a different way, but I believe what I said works.

Comment: @Curious...yes indeed  $|x| \geq 2R \Rightarrow \frac{2|y||x|}{|x|^2}=\frac{2|y|}{|x|} \leq 1$..Then +1 from me..Nice answer.